# What's the most efficient way to compute the mode in a sliding window over a 2D array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, mode, sliding-window

I have an RGBA image that I need to upscale while keeping it smooth.

The catch is that I need to keep the colors exactly the way they are (background: I'm resizing a map where provinces are color-coded), and so I cannot just perform a resize with bicubic interpolation, because that will also interpolate the pixel colors while smoothing.

Thus, in order to get smooth edges I was hoping to upscale using nearest neighbor (giving me staircase patterns) and then round out the edges by replacing each pixel in the target image with the pixel color that occurs most often within a certain radius, a la so:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
amount=3
image=Image.open(<file>)
image=image.filter(ImageFilter.ModeFilter(amount))
```

This finishes fairly quickly, except that it doesn't work, as PIL's ImageFilters operate separately on each channel. **shakes fist**

I tried resorting to numpy arrays and doing the following in a loop:

```
dest[x,y]=Counter([tuple(e) for e in reshape(source[max(x-r,0):x+r+1,max(y-r,0):y+r+1],(-1,4))]).most_common()[0][0]
```

Note that dest and source here are the same shape XxYx4 arrays, hence the necessary reshaping and converting into tuples.
In theory this would work, but would take 12 hours to finish for the **82 million pixel** image I am operating on.  I am inferring that this is mostly due to unnecessary overhead with casting and reshaping.

What would be the appropriate way to do this in Python?

I am about ready to throw up my hands and write a C++ module to do this task.
Anything to steer me away from this path would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you ever seen this? I've had to resort to inline C++ several times before for similar image processing tasks before and... if you're looking at 82 million pixels, this sounds like an excellent candidate for some C++ heavy lifting. [PerformancePython](http://www.scipy.org/PerformancePython)

Comment: Typically when I've had to speed up operations on numpy arrays I've either tried to find a clever way to let numpy handle all of the work, or used python iterators. It's hard for me to figure out what is going on in your second code snippet. Could you provide a simple example with a smaller array?

Comment: @Ancallan That link was an eye-opener.  I threw together some C and inlined it, achieving a speedup of x500. If your comment was a solution I would accept it.  There's still a problem that I have to rely on people having access to scipy and a compiler, but I guess I can live with that!

Answer (score 1):

If you care about a fixed set of colors in your image, the "Palette" image mode would perhaps be more appropriate (at least, if you don't have more than 256 colors in your map).

I would suggest to first convert your image to the "P" mode (Since I'm not really familiar with PIL, I'm not sure, how easy that is. Perhaps you'll have to explicitely construct the palette first?) and then apply the mode filter.

Another solution which comes into my mind is to simply use bicubic interpolation when upsizing and then converting to a palette image using a palette derived from the original image. That might yield better results (and be easier to implement) than your current approach.

Comment: Alas, I have over 2000 colors.
This solution would've been great otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

EPX described in [Image_scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) introduces no new colors. Scale 2x does this:

```
  A    --\ 1 2
C P B  --/ 3 4
  D 

IF C==A => 1=A
IF A==B => 2=B
...
```

and scale 3x is described there too.
Apart from that, I'd agree with "go straight to C" -- depends on what you know.
Has anyone used [np_inline](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~johnl/np_inline/doc-0.3.html) ?